# Incorrect key mappings in remote NX session

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, freenx

I'm using the NoMachine provided NX client on Ubuntu 10.10 running on a laptop. I'm connecting to a FreeNX server that happens to be running on openSUSE.

I'm having trouble with keys being incorrect in the remote session. The most noticable example is that when I press up cursor, the screen shot dialog appears instead. As far as I can gather easily, the cursor keys and delete are affected.

It's worth noting that it doesn't display the same behaviour if I dual boot to Windows XP, or from a different machine using openSUSE.

I'm not really sure where to begin looking. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Well a quick google turned this up http://www.nomachine.com/tr/view.php?id=TR11F02131
Briefly, they advise updating. I see the same issues on 10.04, I think I am running version 1.3. I will probably update eventually